# Compilation failure when building Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-jee

I'm trying to build a Maven project using Eclipse, I am using the command "clean install" to build this application, however I got the error shown bellow.

the pom.xml file includes those dependencies:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>ma.manager.backoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>bookManager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../bookManager</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>bookManager</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/config/${env}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I've tried those steps:

- Updating the project;
- Clean project then run clean install
- Downloading the dependencies manually
- Importing the project several times
- Checking the java version:

[image]

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.956 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-01T08:40:27+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project bookManager: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[5,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[6,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[7,38] package org.apache.struts2.interceptor does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[9,31] package com.opensymphony.xwork2 does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[13,32] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class ActionSupport
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[13,57] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class SessionAware
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[11,2] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class Namespace
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[12,2] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class ParentPackage
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[8,31] package com.opensymphony.xwork2 does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[9,31] package com.opensymphony.xwork2 does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[10,36] package com.opensymphony.xwork2.util does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[12,39] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class ActionSupport
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[4,25] package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[5,32] package javax.servlet.jsp.tagext does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[9,33] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class TagSupport
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[16,40] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class JspException
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.tag.Category
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[3,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[4,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[5,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[6,48] package org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[8,31] package com.opensymphony.xwork2 does not exist
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[13,36] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class ActionSupport
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[11,2] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class Namespace
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[12,2] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class ParentPackage
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[22,10] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Action
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.WelcomeAction
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[28,10] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Action
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.WelcomeAction
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/WelcomeAction.java:[35,10] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Action
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.WelcomeAction
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/MasterAction.java:[15,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[21,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[24,9] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ActionContext
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[24,28] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   variable ActionContext
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[25,9] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ValueStack
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[30,17] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   method addActionError(java.lang.String)
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[35,17] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   method addActionError(java.lang.String)
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/action/exception/ExceptionHandler.java:[41,25] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   method addActionError(java.lang.String)
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.action.exception.ExceptionHandler
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[20,25] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   variable pageContext
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.tag.Category
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[25,35] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class JspException
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.tag.Category
    [ERROR] /D:/Category/bookManager/src/main/java/ma/manager/backoffice/tag/Category.java:[27,24] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   variable SKIP_BODY
    [ERROR]   location: class ma.manager.backoffice.tag.Category
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: a lot of jar files seem to be missing - are they in your pom?

Comment: Yes they exist in the pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

Comment: can you share your POM file

Comment: Yes, it's in the main question

Comment: @Angelika Updated the answer, once please check if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Update:

From the snapshot, it looks like your JRE System library is set to Java SE 1.7 where as the JARs are of version 1.8.0_251. In POM, change the Source and Target versions to 1.8. Also please remove the installed JRE and  change that to JDK 1.8.0_251. Do a project clean and rebuild after that.

[image]

Click remove and then add library.

[image]

Choose the JDK 1.8 which you have

[image]

Also check the compiler level:

[image]

---

Probably you are missing some dependencies (as the log says some packages not found)
Do you have these dependencies in your pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, if you wish to get more information, please add a comment

Comment: @ScaryWombat I dont understand what's the problem in my answer format. I edited it.

Comment: Maybe (contrary to what we both believe) the dependencies are in the pom, then the OP has some other issue, but unless this key information is known, then we are just guessing - eh.

Comment: true. I believe in the process of improvising the answer step by step as the requirements / issues keep getting clearer from the asker.

Comment: Believe what you want, but people may downvote you ;-)

Comment: Hmm, updated question, seems that the dependencies are already there after all.